# MonoDevelop debugging error

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I've recently changed to Ubuntu 11.10 (from Windows Vista).I use mono (2.8.5) as my IDE (C# VS.net before) to program.

As a quick test I want to make a console program with the following code:

```
using System;

namespace DeleteMe1
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
        Console.ReadKey ();
    }
}
}
```

If I run the program I see a screen appear and disappear (very quickly). When I debug I get the following error:

```
Could not open port for debugger. Another process may be using the port.
```

Is someone familiar with these messages? I've already tried the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8...using-the-port

But the property key (Property key="MonoTouch.Debugger.Port" value="10000") is not available.

Whats wrong?

Thanks in advance and with best regards.